# Is the Authorize.net payment model in 1.7.0.2 compatible with post-Poodle changes?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, authorize.net, ssl

I recently received a notification that Authorize.net will no longer support SSL3 due to the Poodle vulnerability. I would assume that a version of Magento as new as 1.7.0.2 doesn't use SSL3 in its authorize payment module, but hav no way to verify that other than asking here. Is it correct that the Authorize.net module will continue to work without SSL3, or will I need to upgrade Magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not related to Magento but your server instead.

You should check with your hosting provider on whether they still rely on SSLv3 and more importantly, if they have disabled SSLv3 after the POODLE bug has been discovered.

Chances are, your server should not rely on SSLv3 only so Authorize.net's action will not affect you (except for your website visitors who are using Internet Explorer 6 on Windows XP which both should not be used anymore as they have reached their End of Life).

What you should be more worried about is whether SSLv3 has been disabled in your server (it should be disabled).

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the belated reply. I was erroneously expecting an email notification, so didn't see yours until now.